# AngularJS $http posting object containing array strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, python, json, angularjs

I have a function which uses $http to post params.  The thing I don't understand is that the `filters` param contains an array.  However, the server interprets this array as a key/value pair for each item in the array.  Why?  Is this an AngularJS or server-side issue?

```
var updateCandidates = function (slot) {
    console.log(slot.filters)
    $http({method: 'POST', url: '/api/slot_candidates', params: {
        type: slot.type,
        start_date: slot.start_date,
        end_date: slot.end_date,
        filters: slot.filters
    }}).success(function (response) {
        return response
    }).error(function (response) {
        $rootScope.modalAlert('error', 'Something happened', true)
    })
}

# request.params.  Note the duplicate 'filters' key

NestedMultiDict([(u'end_date', u'2014-12-30T14:00:00'), (u'filters', u'{"operator":"contains","group":"program","type":"unicode","name":"title","query":"joan of arc"}'), (u'filters', u'{"operator":"contains","group":"program","type":"unicode","name":"aspect_ratio","query":"16"}'), (u'start_date', u'2014-08-25T00:00:00'), (u'type', u'Program')])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too a long time ago, seems this is the behavior of angular $http post, you can't post parameter with array directly, I think it's a good way to post them with JSON,

```
var updateCandidates = function (slot) {
console.log(slot.filters)
var data = {
    type: slot.type,
    start_date: slot.start_date,
    end_date: slot.end_date,
    filters: slot.filters
};

$http({
  method: 'POST', 
  url: '/api/slot_candidates',
  responseType  : "json",
  params: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers:{
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
  }).success(function (response) {
    return response
  }).error(function (response) {
    $rootScope.modalAlert('error', 'Something happened', true)
  })
}
```

but make sure your server support json data too.